# Scheduled message passing from server to clients: what system to use?

Tags: python, node.js, celery, messaging

I want to be able to schedule delivery of a lightweight message from a server to a client. This is new territory to me so I'd appreciate some advice on the possible approaches available.

The client is running on a Raspberry Pi using node.js (because I'm using node libraries to control a piece of attached hardware). Eventually there will be multiple clients like it.

The server could be anything, though I'm most familiar with Python, django and node.

I want to  be able to access the server from a browser and cause it to schedule a future message to the client, effectively a push notification with a tiny bit of data.

I'm looking at pub-sub and messaging systems to do this; I started writing a system that uses node on both ends and sockets, but the approach I want is more fire-and-forget occasional messages, not constant realtime data exchange. I'm also not a huge fan of the node-cron style scheduling, I'd like to be able to retrieve and alter scheduled events and it felt somewhat heavy-handed to layer this on top of a cron system.

My current solution uses python on the server (so I can write a django web interface) with celery and rabbitmq, using a named queue per client. The client subscribes to that specific queue using node-amqp, and off we go. This also allows me to create queues that multiple clients can be interested in, which is a neat bonus.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848024/is-celery-appropriate-for-use-with-many-small-distributed-systems) makes me think I'm doing the right thing -- but as I'm new to this stuff, it feels like I might be missing something. Are there alternatives I should consider in the world of server-client messaging?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using python you could take a look at python remote objects, ([pyro](http://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/)).